# Increase volume of PC?

Tags: windows, video, music, audio

If I download any video, I can get enough volume because of VLC player. But when I play video online, like on YouTube or any other site, volume is really less.

Can you please suggest any software which can amplify volume of my whole PC, as it is possible with VLC player.

I am using Windows XP and mostly use Chrome browser.

Comment: Have you verified the system volume isnt set super low.  This seems like a strange issue and something software won't fix.  Are you talking about ALL online videos or just some?  Some videos just don't have good sound...

Comment: @James Just some videos. But sometimes very important one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[::Try this::](http://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/259570-how-further-increase-speaker-volume.html#post2143810):

1. Right click on the speaker next to the clock.
2. Go to Playback devices,
3. then right click on Speakers
4. and go to Properties.
5. Here you find a button for Enhancements.
6. Maybe playing with those will help. Be aware though that
   enhancements take CPU cycles.
7. In particular, Loudness Equalization, if your system has it.

This works well on Win 7 with Realtek Audio drivers..

For WinXP, you'll need to check if your audio drivers support "Loudness Equalization" or not. If they're realtek, then you can try [::this too::](http://forums.randi.org/showpost.php?s=86373de914360810d1ea725a1509d5d8&p=8180399&postcount=8):

> Post from http://www.sevenforums.com/
>
> Googling |speakers equalizer| turned out to be the real key. The sound
> card uses Realtek AC97 drivers and with a minor degree of difficulty I
> downloaded and installed Realtek's Sound Effect graphic equalizer
> which, although it is huge on the screen and does not incorporate a
> volume control (I'm using MS's Volume Control for that), does affect
> the speakers.

[image: Increase Volume]

Comment: `Realtek Audio drivers` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Windows XP doesn't have an embedded equalizer and doesn't provide any hooks or APIs for developing one for it. The only chance you have on Windows XP is to have an equalizer from your audio hardware manufacturer. You need to detect your sound card and look for a specialized equalizer for it. It may be available as part of the driver installation or as a separate download. See, for example, Realtek Equalizer.